# C sockets - randomly receiving more than one string at a time

Tags: java, c, sockets, nio

I have encountered an interesting C sockets problem.

I am receiving incoming strings and noticed that I will, randomly, receive 3 strings at a same time for the first 2 ~ 4 strings.

For example, I am receiving the following incoming strings.

```
1~message~i love you\r\n
2~message~do you love me?\r\n
3~message~when are we going to meet again?\r\n 
4~message~How about now?\r\n
5~message~Oh! I'm pregnant!\r\n
```

I added a counter to track the number of messages received and noticed that the counter *sometimes* does not count the first 3 strings. For example

```
1~message~i love you\r\n
->Line 1 received
2~message~do you love me?\r\n
3~message~when are we going to meet again?\r\n
4~message~How about now?\r\n
->Line 2 received
5~message~Oh! I'm pregnant!\r\n
->Line 3 received
```

The following is my code for printing the line number

```
int lineNo = 1;
while ((recvBytes = recv(clntSockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) > 0) {
    printf("%s", buffer);
    memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("Line %d received\n", lineNo++);
}
```

I'm not sure why is this happening since this problem did not appear when i coded in Java nio.

Any ideas, folks?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are using TCP, relating recv() calls to "messages" (or "lines") in your case is flawed. TCP, conceptually, is a stream of bytes. The sending operating system is free to group multiple send() calls into a single IP packet, as is the receiving operating system free to report multiple incoming packets as a single recv() call (assuming the buffer is large enough). It may even choose to split an incoming packet across recv calls.

So you really need to put a message structure in the data itself, eg. by scanning for line breaks in the data received.

That this didn't occur in Java was pure luck.

Comment: Over loopback, you tend to get packets in the sizes they were sent.  However over a real network, this is very hard to avoid coalescing packets. If you send the packets about 100 ms apart, you usually get the packets in the sizes they were sent, but you shouldn't rely on this behaviour.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the heads up. i think i'll scan for line breaks like what martin suggested. Had been thinking about it during my dinner. Now that I'm back, would probably potter about it a bit more. Was looking at strtok() and strtok_r(). strtok_r() looks like a better bet because the documentation says its good for threading. Further, I'm intending to break the string "1~message~I love you\r\n" into each token of "1" "message" "I love you".

Answer (score 1):

You are not reading till end of line. The `buffer` can contain *more than one line*.

Answer (score 0):

what connection type are you using?

UDP is unreliable most of the time.

TCP is much better than UDP in terms of reliability.